# How do I clear cache with Python Requests?

Tags: python, python-requests

Does the `requests` package of Python cache data by default?

For example,

```
import requests
resp = requests.get('https://some website')
```

Will the response be cached? If so, how do I clear it?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Python-requests doesn't have any caching features.

However, if you need them you can look at [requests-cache](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests-cache), although I never used it.

Comment: This should be the

Answer (score 36):

Add a `'Cache-Control: no-cache'` header:

```
self.request = requests.get('http://google.com',
                            headers={'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'})
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/55613686/469045 for complete answer.

Comment: But... Why would you specify a header if `Python-requests` anyway never caches?

Comment: Good question, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/55613686/469045 for a more complete answer with references & links.  But (and kinda guessing) caching is part of how HTTP works, maybe a proxy is caching something in between the client and the origin server.

Comment: @jones77 so this needs only if a proxy used?

Comment: @SmartManoj no, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/55613686/469045 it's an http server-side feature

Answer (score 28):

Late answer, but [python requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/)  **doesn't cache requests,** you should use the `Cache-Control` and `Pragma` headers instead, i.e.:

```
import requests
h = {
    ...
    "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
    "Pragma": "no-cache"
}
r = requests.get("url", headers=h)
...
```

---

[HTTP/Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers)

- > [`Cache-Control`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control)
  > The Cache-Control general-header field is used to specify directives for caching mechanisms in both requests and responses. Caching directives are unidirectional, meaning that a given directive in a request is not implying that the same directive is to be given in the response.
- > [`Pragma`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Pragma)
  > Implementation-specific header that may have various effects anywhere
  > along the request-response chain. Used for backwards compatibility
  > with HTTP/1.0 caches where the Cache-Control header is not yet
  > present.

---

**Directive**

- > [`no-cache`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control#Directives)
  > Forces caches to submit the request to the origin server for
  > validation before releasing a cached copy.

---

Note on `Pragma`:

> Pragma is not specified for HTTP responses and is therefore not a
> reliable replacement for the general HTTP/1.1 Cache-Control header,
> although it does behave the same as Cache-Control: no-cache, if the
> Cache-Control header field is omitted in a request. Use Pragma only
> for backwards compatibility with HTTP/1.0 clients.

Comment: If it is as you say that the requests library doesn't do any caching, why would there be a need to specify headers to control a behavior that isn't present anyway?

Comment: The client side (python requests) isn't caching the request, but the server may be using some sort of caching and we're explicitly requesting a _fresh version_ of the content.

Comment: @PedroLobito Why the servers will give an outdated version?

Comment: @SmartManoj Because you expressly request so by using the headers mentioned above.

Comment: Why did one explicitly request outdated version?

Comment: The client side (python requests) isn't caching the request, but the server may be using some sort of caching and we're explicitly requesting a fresh version of the content.

Answer (score 9):

Requests does not do caching by default. You can easily plug it in by using something like [CacheControl](http://cachecontrol.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

Answer (score 0):

I was getting outdated version of a website and I thought about requests cache too, but adding no-cache parameter to headers didn't change anything. It appears that the cookie I was passing, was causing the server to present outdated site.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you managed the cookie? I'm having the same problem but am unaware of passing any cookies in my requests.

Comment: Hi, I copied the cookie from HTTP request in browser's devtools and used it in Python, because it seemed to contain some properties that should be presented by a normal user visiting the website. I wanted the script to look like a user. After removing that cookie I managed to get refreshed version of the website, but in the end it didn't help long term. Maybe some websites have built-in mechanism to present outdated versions of website to clients that they detect to be suspicious.

Comment: @user4463876 why not blocking the request itself instead of giving outdated?

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
h = {
    ...
    "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
    "Pragma": "no-cache",
    "Expires": "0"
}
r = requests.get("url", headers=h)
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You added  `"Expires": "0"` to what was suggested in previous answers. Can you explain what this does in addition to the rest? I'll be happy to upvote with a helpful explanation.

Comment: you request from the server that it's response will expire immediately @joanis