# python requests...or something else... mysteriously caching? hashes don't change right when file does

Tags: python, caching, python-requests

I have a very odd bug.  I'm writing some code in python3 to check a url for changes by comparing sha256 hashes.  The relevant part of the code is as follows:

```
from requests import get
from hashlib import sha256

def fetch_and_hash(url):
    file = get(url, stream=True)
    f = file.raw.read()
    hash = sha256()
    hash.update(f)
    return hash.hexdigest()

def check_url(target): # passed a dict containing hash from previous examination of url
    t = deepcopy(target)
    old_hash = t["hash"]
    new_hash = fetch_and_hash(t["url"])
    if old_hash == new_hash:
        t["justchanged"] = False
        return t
    else:
        t["justchanged"] = True
        return handle_changes(t, new_hash) # records the changes
```

So I was testing this on an old webpage of mine.  I ran the check, recorded the hash, and then changed the page.  Then I re-ran it a few times, and the code above did not reflect a new hash (i.e., it followed the `old_hash == new_hash` branch).

Then I waited maybe 5 minutes and ran it again without changing the code at all except to add a couple of debugging calls to `print()`.  And this time, it worked.

Naturally, my first thought was "huh, requests must be keeping a cache for a few seconds."  But then I googled around and learned that [requests doesn't cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20198274/how-do-i-clear-cache-with-python-requests).

Again, I changed *no code* except for print calls.  You might not believe me. You might think "he must have changed something else."  But I didn't! I can prove it! [Here's the commit!](https://github.com/paultopia/minitrue/commit/f0bc9be21174a4c18cdf7eb46f8643bdf5fd68bc)

So what gives?  Does anyone know why this is going on?  If it matters, the webpage is hosted on a standard commercial hosting service, IIRC using Apache, and I'm on a lousy local phone company DSL connection---don't know if there are any serverside caching settings going on, but it's not on any kind of CDN.

So I'm trying to figure out whether there is some mysterious ISP cache thing going on, or I'm somehow misusing requests... the former I can handle; the latter I need to fix!