# Requests return the same data

Tags: python, python-requests

I using python requests module to grab data from one website. 
At first time i run script, all works fine, data is ok. Then, if run script again, it's return the same data, however  this data changed on website if opened in browser. Whenever i run script, data still the same. BUT!
After 5 or 6 minutes, if run script again, data was updated. Looks like requests caching info.
If using the browser, every time hit refresh, data updates correctly.

```
r = requests.get('https://verysecretwebsite.com', headers=headers)
r.text
```

Actually i use following header:

```
headers = {'User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 YaBrowser/19.6.1.153 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36",
'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
'Referer': 'https://www.gismeteo.ru/weather-orenburg-5159/now/',
'DNT': '1',
'Connection': 'false',
'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, max-age=0',
'TE': 'Trailers'}
```

but with no luck.
I try grub this link https://www.gismeteo.ru/weather-orenburg-5159/now/ with section "data-dateformat="G:i"

Answer (score 1):

In your code you haven't set any headers. This means that `requests` will always send its default `User-Agent` header like `User-Agent: python-requests/2.22.0` and use no caching directives like `Cache-Control`.

The remote server of your website may have different caching policies for client applications. Remote server can respond with different data or use different caching time based on `User-Agent` and/or `Cache-Control` headers of your request.

So try to check what headers your browser uses (<kbd>F12</kbd> in Chrome) to make requests to your site and then add them to your request. You can also add `Cache-Control` directive to force server to return the most recent data.

Example:

```py
import requests

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 YaBrowser/19.6.1.153 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36",
    "Cache-Control": "no-cache, max-age=0",  # disable caching
}
r = requests.get("https://www.mysecretURL.com", headers=headers)
```

Comment: then you should edit your question, because currently there is no info about headers you're using

Comment: Added additional info to my question.

Answer (score 0):

The requests.get() method doesn't cache data by default (from [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20198274/how-do-i-clear-cache-with-python-requests)) I'm not entirely sure of the reason for the lag, as refreshing your browser is essentially identical to calling requests.get(). You could try creating a loop that automatically collects data every 5-10 seconds or so, and that should work fine (and keep you from having to manually run the same lines of code). Hope this helps!