# How can I reset and re-run this code every 2 minutes in python? The while loop fails for me

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I need help to be able to run this code and get an update price every 2 minutes.

I tried the while loop but it stops throwing values after the first scrape. Only the date and time in the result is refreshed, not the price.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


result = requests.get("https://liveindex.org/s&p-futures/")
src = result.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'lxml')
table_body=soup.find('tbody')
rows = table_body.find_all('tr')

for row in rows:
    cols=row.find_all('td')
    cols=[x.text.strip() for x in cols]
    print(cols)
```

I need to create a live ticker to get the latest stock prices. The code can scrape the price but only once. A manual restart works but that's not what I want.

Comment: I don't know much about python requests, but maybe there's a cache somewhere messing you up? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20198274/how-do-i-clear-cache-with-python-requests. Python requests aren't cached, but maybe it's something on the server side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try every other minute for eternity:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import time # you need this module

# this will run forever
while True:
    result = requests.get("https://liveindex.org/s&p-futures/")
    src = result.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'lxml')
    table_body=soup.find('tbody')
    rows = table_body.find_all('tr')

    for row in rows:
        cols=row.find_all('td')
        cols=[x.text.strip() for x in cols]
        print(cols)

    time.sleep(120) # this will wait for 120 seconds
```

Answer (score -3):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
**import time**

**While True:**
result = requests.get("https://liveindex.org/s&p-futures/")
src = result.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'lxml')
table_body=soup.find('tbody')
rows = table_body.find_all('tr')

for row in rows:
cols=row.find_all('td')
cols=[x.text.strip() for x in cols]
print(cols)
**time.sleep(120)**
```

Comment: This isn't valid code, does nothing to explain why the OP's isn't working, nor does it address the problem in that multiple requests are yielding un-updated data. If you must, add comments to the code block indicating where you added code, and indent properly please. Don't forget to test it yourself before posting.