# is there any way i can make a get request refresh all the time?

Tags: python, python-requests

so i want to code something that notifies me whenever something changes in an API within seconds, but i cant find a way to make the requests.get refresh all the time

any way to do that?

Comment: Can you share some more detail with code snippet ?

Comment: what you probably need is a webhook https://django.cowhite.com/blog/creating-webhooks-with-django/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you are talking about some scheduler

you can try this one [over here](https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

so your code would look something like that

```
import schedule

def make_request():
    # your code goes here


schedule.every.minute.do(make_request)
```

But I suggest you to use web-sockets or producer-consumer pattern to achieve your goal.
Example: publish your changed data from one service (producer) to RabbitMQ queue and listen to that queue with another service (consumer)

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```py
import requests
headers = {
    ...
    "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
    "Pragma": "no-cache"
}
x = requests.get("https://example.com", headers=headers)
```

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55613686/6696746).