# How to only download updated CSV files via Python requests?

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to download CSV files from: 
[Download sports fixtures, schedules and results as CSV, XLSX, ICS and JSON](https://fixturedownload.com/).

I have a python program that downloads the files I am looking for. The problem is the files that are being downloaded are not up-to-date. It is currently May and one of the files downloaded is out of date all the way back to November while some are actually up to date.

There is no consistency that I can see and I have run out of ideas on how to fix it. I have tried to touch all the file and folders involved to get the most recent timestamp. I have tried to clear all of the `.pyc` files. Nothing seems to work. Here is the code I am using:

```
base_url = 'https://fixturedownload.com/download/'

csv_file_names = [
    'epl-2021-chelsea-EasternStandardTime.csv' ,
    'champions-league-2021-chelsea-EasternStandardTime.csv',
    'la-liga-2021-fc-barcelona-EasternStandardTime.csv',
    'champions-league-2021-barcelona-EasternStandardTime.csv',
    'ligue-1-2021-paris-saint-germain-EasternStandardTime.csv',
    'champions-league-2021-paris-EasternStandardTime.csv',
    'epl-2021-EasternStandardTime.csv',
    'champions-league-2021-EasternStandardTime.csv',
    'mlb-2021-baltimore-orioles-EasternStandardTime.csv',
    'nfl-2020-pittsburgh-steelers-EasternStandardTime.csv'
]

count = 0
led_count = 0

for csv in csv_file_names:
    print("Downloading...", count+1, "of", len(csv_file_names), "-", csv  )
    r = requests.get( base_url+csv, allow_redirects=True)
    open( '/home/pi/Score-Checker/CSV-Files/'+csv, 'wb').write(r.content)
    count += 1
```

Comment: I’m not familiar with this site, but is it possible some of the files you are downloading didn’t have any updates beyond November? For example, the Baltimore Orioles’ 2021 season ended in early October; a file last updated in November could very well include the entire dataset for that team.

Comment: Thats a good thought. To answer your question: No. The files are updated regularly. The particular file I was referencing was "champions-league-2021-EasternStandardTime.csv"

Comment: Might have to open a question/issue with the website, since they are responsible for providing the data files. Assuming your url strings are correct, I don’t see anything in your script that would necessarily prevent you from obtaining their most recent (and perhaps only?) version of each file they are offering.

Comment: UPDATE: I went directly to one of the links in my web browser and the file downloaded (it was the correct and updated file) then I ran the program again and the updated file was downloaded. I feel like this may have something to do with my browsers cache?

Comment: Interesting … If it is caching that is causing the issue, and you are using the requests module, perhaps this thread can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20198274/how-do-i-clear-cache-with-python-requests

Comment: I would try to explicitly `.close()` files or using it `with open(...) as f:`

Comment: Matt, That link is a good idea but doesnt seem to do any good. 
Andrej, there is no need for that when Im downloading them since im not opening them at that point. BUT when I do open them I used with and they read just fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to pull the json feed instead of the download csv? Requires a slight change to your csv_file_names list. (Which if you need me to, we can work off your original list and just use regex to grab the relevant parts to place in the url).

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import re


csv_file_names = [
    ['epl-2021','chelsea'] ,
    ['champions-league-2021','chelsea'],
    ['la-liga-2021','fc-barcelona'],
    ['champions-league-2021','barcelona'],
    ['ligue-1-2021','paris-saint-germain'],
    ['champions-league-2021','paris'],
    ['epl-2021', ''],
    ['champions-league-2021',''],
    ['mlb-2021','baltimore-orioles'],
    ['nfl-2020','pittsburgh-steelers']
]

for count, each in enumerate(csv_file_names, start=1):
    url = 'https://fixturedownload.com/feed/json/%s/%s' %(each[0], each[-1])
    jsonData = requests.get(url).json()
    df = pd.DataFrame(jsonData)
    
    csv = '%s-%s-.csv' %(each[0], each[-1])
    print("Downloading...", count, "of", len(csv_file_names), "-", csv  )
    
    for col in ['HomeTeamScore', 'AwayTeamScore']:
        df[col] = df[col].fillna(99).astype(int).astype(str)
    
    df['Result'] = df['HomeTeamScore'] + ' - ' + df['AwayTeamScore']
    df['Result'] = df['Result'].replace('99 - 99', '')
    
    for col in df.columns:
        if 'Date' in col:
            newColName = 'Date'
        else:
            newColName = ' '.join(re.sub('([A-Z][a-z]+)', r' \1', re.sub('([A-Z]+)', r' \1', col)).split())
        df = df.rename(columns={col:newColName})
        
    df = df.drop(['Group', 'Home Team Score', 'Away Team Score'], axis=1)




    
    df.to_csv('/home/pi/Score-Checker/CSV-Files/'+csv, index=False)
```

**Output: of `'ligue-1-2021','paris-saint-germain'`**

[image]

Comment: 1. Im not trying to download anything json. The files download just fine. They just arent updated. I expect it has something to do with my raspberry pi's cache.
2. I tried running your code and it didnt like 'f' preceding the url string. After I removed them I got an error on line 21 with the jsonData variable.

Comment: Yes I know, but it's possible that the json requests will fetch live/updated dated since it's getting the data in the raw form. I updated the code to change the format string. What was the error you got with line 21?

Comment: You may be onto something here. I tried to run it and it worked (although I had to get rid of the f string for the csv variable and use the %s like the url variable).
I am referencing the ligue-1-2021-paris-saint-germain-EasternStandardTime.csv file in the next comment.

Comment: Here are lines from the csv file from my code and your code (in that order):
- 349,35,01/05/2022 15:00,Stade de la Meinau,RC Strasbourg Alsace,Paris Saint-Germain,
- 34,Paris Saint-Germain,3.0,2022-04-29 19:00:00Z,,RC Strasbourg Alsace,3.0,Stade de la Meinau,349,35

So the first line (my code) is in the correct format BUT the date is inaccurate.
The second line(your code) is in an incorrect format BUT the date is correct.

If you know how to combine the two that would be the solution I am looking for.
(Also, if a game has been played then the score will show up at the end of the line)

Comment: Ya I can fix this. I’ll look at it tomorrow and update the code.

Comment: What do you mean by incorrect format?

Comment: Also, your date and times arent incorrect. They’re in eastern time zone, which is what you request for the csv.

Comment: I can only assume that by incorrect format, you mean that the csv headers don't exactly match to the json. To that I would say, 1st technically, the format isn't "incorrect", thats just the nature of the raw data. 2nd, you should look up some basic pandas tutorials. It's just a matter of manipulating the table, changing a column name, etc. Pretty standard stuff which you should familiarise yourself with. I adjusted the code to get it to match the csv download format.

Comment: 1. I think you can ignore that comment. That was knee-jerk reaction. After I took a closer look at the csv file I noticed all the information was there.
2. The format doesnt really matter. I can just alter the script that reads the files. Its no big deal.
3. YOUR SCRIPT WORKS! I did a download a couple of hours ago and then they updated the csv file a few minutes ago and I did another download. Both times the files had the up to date info in them. 
Thank you for your help. Good job.

PS Im all over those panda tutorials.

Comment: Ya no worries. I just wasn’t sure what you meant and had to make assumptions to try to address it. Adjust whatever you need to adjust. It just appeared the csv path has sort of some additional processing it does…and apparently falls apart at some  point on their end. While the json looks to be the data source in its raw form. I always opt for the raw data, then I can choose how I want to deal with it (date time zones, column names, etc.).

Comment: And just ignore/delete the part between the print statement and the .to_csv as that’s just all to get it to look like the csv it downloads.