# Code works incorrectly after Exception - even with loop/try+except etc

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I'm trying to make decoder, data-->json. You paste raw data, and it decodes it into json. Here are 2 scenarios:

1. FIRST input is a correct data, it then correctly decodes it into json.
2. FIRST input is random string, like "abcd" - code then says that data is invalid.

After second scenario, even when you try to put VALID data, it will say "invalid data" forever. How can make it work, so when you first write "abcd", and then paste valid data, it will just decode it?! I tried loops, breaks, continues... Nothing works, and typing invalid input ruins whole code - you have to restart program and paste VALID data.

```
import requests
import json

while True:
    try:
        raw = input('Please paste raw data: '+"\n")
        url = 'https://platform.lobaro.com/api/mbus?raw={}'.format(raw)
        print("\n")

        get = requests.get(url)
        json_body = get.json()

        parsed = json.dumps(json_body)
        parsed2 = json.loads(parsed)
        
        formatted = json.dumps(json.loads(parsed), indent=2)
        print(formatted+"\n")

        print("INFORMATIONS:")
        name = parsed2["MFieldLongString"]
        print(f'Producer: {name}')

        l1 = parsed2["Length"]
        print(f'Lenght: {l1}'+'\n')
        print('============================================================================')
        
    except requests.exceptions.JSONDecodeError:
        print('Invalid data! Could not parse to JSON.'+"\n")
        continue
```

Comment: Are you sure about that webpage? It's saying `502 Bad Gateway`

Comment: it works fine for me, code uses site's API - or you can decode on webpage

Comment: you probably tried 'https://platform.lobaro.com/api/mbus?raw={}' which is incorrect - it's just a variable for this data, if you want to visit, it's:  https://platform.lobaro.com/#/wmbus/parser

Answer (score 3):

The site uses other API URL to decode wmbus messages:

```py
import json
import requests

api_url = "https://platform.lobaro.com/gqlgen/query"
payload = {
    "operationName": None,
    "query": "query ($raw: String!, $key: String) {\n  wmbus: parseWmbus(raw: $raw, key: $key) {\n    data\n    parseError\n    __typename\n  }\n}\n",
    "variables": {
        "key": "0102030405060708090A0B0C0D0E0F11",   # <-- change this field
        "raw": "2e44931578563412330333637a2a0020055923c95aaa26d1b2e7493b2a8b013ec4a6f6d3529b520edff0ea6defc955b29d6d69ebf3ec8a",   # <-- change this field
    },
}

data = requests.post(api_url, json=payload).json()
if data['data']['wmbus']['parseError'] == "":
    data = json.loads(data["data"]["wmbus"]["data"])
    print(data)
```

Prints:

```json
{
    "Raw": "0x2e4493157856341233037a2a0020055923c95aaa26d1b2e7493b013ec4a6f6d3529b520edff0ea6defc99d6d69ebf3",
    "RawWithCrc": "0x2e44931578563412330333637a2a0020055923c95aaa26d1b2e7493b2a8b013ec4a6f6d3529b520edff0ea6defc955b29d6d69ebf3ec8a",
    "FrameFormat": "A",
    "Length": 46,
    "CField": "0x44",
    "CFieldString": "0x44 (SND_NR)",
    "MField": "0x9315",
    "MFieldCodeString": "ELS",
    "MFieldLongString": "Elster GmbH, Germany, Europe",
    "Id": 305419896,
    "IdString": "12345678",
    "Version": 51,
    "Device": "0x03",
    "DeviceString": "Gas",
    "CiField": "0x7a",
    "HeaderKnown": True,
    "PayloadKnown": True,
    "CrcValid": True,
    "HasCrc": True,
    "SourceType": "WMBUS",
    "IsCompactFrame": False,
    "FormatSignature": 61330,
    "FormatFrame": "0x0c14046d02fd17",
    "Header": {
        "Serial": 0,
        "IdString": "",
        "ManufacturerCode": 0,
        "MFieldCodeString": "",
        "MFieldLongString": "",
        "Version": 0,
        "DeviceType": "0x00",
        "DeviceString": "",
        "EncryptionMode": 5,
        "EncryptionModeString": "AES with CBC",
        "EncryptedBlocks": 2,
        "HopCount": 0,
        "IsAccessible": True,
        "IsBidirectionalMode": False,
        "IsSynchronous": False,
        "ReservedBit": False,
        "TelegramType": 0,
        "AccessNumber": 42,
        "StatusByte": 0,
        "ConfigField": [32, 5],


...and so on.
```

Comment: You the man! Good detective work  @Andrej Kesely!!

Answer (score 0):

This is because the response could have been cached. One way to disable the caching is to pass the appropriate headers in the request. Something like

```
get = requests.get(url, headers={
                          'Cache-Control': 'no-cache', 
                          'Pragma': 'no-cache', 
                          'Expires': '0' })
```

See 'Pedro Lobitos' answer to this question here for a good explanation here [How do I clear cache with Python Requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20198274/how-do-i-clear-cache-with-python-requests). (Good explanation and very good discussion/comments too)

Comment: It doesn't work, might be code's issue, I guess... Why? Because it works somehow randomly. One time when I firstly put even valid data, it says it's invalid. Or soometimes when I put wrong data, and then correct data - it strangely decodes it. I have no idea...

Comment: Okay, I guess I got it - you have to wait like 15-20sec (after wrong data), before putting another data as input, when you try to paste one data after another, or even 5sec after, it won't work. I don't know why so, it seems to be soo random

Answer (score 0):

You could try to restart a method after the Exception, so you delete all local variables temporarily and restart from scratch:

```
import gc
def myMethod():
    gc.collect(generation=2)
    while True:
        try:
            raw = input('Please paste raw data: '+"\n")
            url = 'https://platform.lobaro.com/api/mbus?raw={}'.format(raw)
            print("\n")

            get = requests.get(url)
            json_body = get.json()

            parsed = json.dumps(json_body)
            parsed2 = json.loads(parsed)
    
            formatted = json.dumps(json.loads(parsed), indent=2)
            print(formatted+"\n")

            print("INFORMATIONS:")
            name = parsed2["MFieldLongString"]
            print(f'Producer: {name}')

            l1 = parsed2["Length"]
            print(f'Lenght: {l1}'+'\n')
            print('=====')
    
        except requests.exceptions.JSONDecodeError:
            print('Invalid data! Could not parse to JSON.'+"\n")
            break

    myMethod()
```

So everytime it raises an Exception, the "old execution" is killed and a new one starts. The gc is there for automatically garbage-collect the leftovers from the old execution.